# Graph isomorphism checking using BFS

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, graph-isomorphism

I have two input graphs, with the same number of nodes and edges and both are rooted and undirected. I need to check whether they are isomorphic with each other or not. If so, I want my algorithm to return the mapping between two graphs. Since both of the graphs are rooted, I am assuming that BFS is going to return faster if they are not isomorphic. Is there any better algorithm or any implementation/article that can help me with this question? Thanks.

Comment: In general this is a difficult problem. One possible direction for heuristics is, if you write out degree sequences, they must coincide, and they strongly limit the number of choices for the bijection... Matlab has a routine you can call for such things

Comment: Are you seeking an algorithm that you will code yourself, or instead some existing software that you can simply apply?

Comment: For an implementation nauty: http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/

Comment: Another alternative is to use SageMath and use the `is_isomorphic` method for graphs: http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/generic_graph.html#sage.graphs.generic_graph.GenericGraph.is_isomorphic

Comment: Thanks @fidbc. I am gonna read on these two but I want to implement the code myself.

Comment: yes @David. I want to implement it myself.

Comment: Thanks @gt6989b, what I have in mind is basically the same thing. I am trying to have a heuristic solution using the degree sequence. I am not sure if there are any other approaches out there that I am unaware of!

Comment: Other than the references linked at nauty's webpage, this is another one that comes to mind:
http://www.combinatorialmath.ca/G&G/articles/isomorphismprograms.pdf

Answer (score 3):

A few thoughts:

Having two rooted graphs does simplify the isomorphism challenge, because you have one known vertex mapping. You can use this root to assign a more detailed initial analysis of vertex degrees:

- Assign each vertex with its distance from the root.
- Now the degree for each vertex can be split into three components: in-degree, across-degree and out-degree, representing the count of those edges that go from that vertex to points of lower distance, the same distance and greater distance respectively.
- the list of 4-tuples: (distance, in-degree, across-degree, out-degree) can be sorted and **must** produce matched lists if the graphs are isomorphic. This also gives an initial partition of the vertices, in the language of the [paper @fidbc linked](http://www.combinatorialmath.ca/G&G/articles/isomorphismprograms.pdf), groups of vertices which can only be mapped within that group.

If any of the 4-tuples turn out to be unique, that is another fixed mapping point and could be used as an alternate root.

Every technique that usually only has degree to work on can work with this sub-divided distance/degree tuple.

You could also sum the outward paths (out-paths) inwards towards the root for a fifth characteristic, each vertex contributing $(1+$out-paths$)$ to each of its inward-linked vertices, if this is likely to be useful. Again the extended  tuples must match count for type across the graphs for isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks so much for the comment. This is an interesting answer. However, when it comes to graphs I do not think having similar list of 4-tuples for two graphs guarantees the isomorphism.

Comment: It doesn't guarantee the isomorphism in one step, but it proves a richer metric to continue the process of proving (or disproving) the isomorphism than simple degree numbers. For sufficiently complicated graphs, especially if expected to be regular or near-regular, this could be valuable. And for simpler graphs there is a reasonable chance that it will establish the isomorphism answer in relatively few steps.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple algorithm for determining if two trees are isomorphic:

1. Label the leaves with '01'
2. Label the parents of the leaves with '0' + sorted(labels(children)) + '1'
3. Repeat until you reach the root

Then you compare root labels.

Comment: The graphs in question are not necessarily trees. Certainly that hasn't been given by the questioner.

Comment: @joffan huh you're quite right. completely misread it...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This solution works for two trees but I am looking for an algorithm to cover graphs as well.

Comment: @Armita  - Yes, quite right. I didn't read your question well enough, apologies. I don't know if rooted graphs are particularly easier than unrooted ones, although it seems like it should be easier.